# How do I set my texts to vibrate differently from other notifications?

Tags: sms, notifications, email

So I switched from iPhone (4s) to Android (Galaxy S5) recently and I love everything except the sound settings. With my iPhone, I could set the phone to vibrate once for emails, twice for texts, and a very short vibrate for other alerts. This way, I could separate texts, emails, and non-urgent alerts without needing to check my phone. How can I do this on my Galaxy S5?